# Does/Will the SurveyMonkey API support exporting PDF's of survey responses?

Tags: pdf, surveymonkey

We can log into our SurveyMonkey account, go to a survey response, and click the "Export" button to Export a PDF. Is there an API method that can return a PDF export for a response (as far as I can tell there is not)? If not, are there any future plans to provide such an API method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently a method to return a PDF export through the API.

Making that available through the API is in consideration but I wouldn't expect to see it soon.

When/if it is available it'll be added to the documentation located at https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3

You can also watch the [public API docs repo](https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/public_api_docs) to stay up to date.